# How to force user to click on a divs in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I had 6 circles. I'm trying to prevent my users to click `NOT` in order from 1-6, from left-right.

**Ex** : Users should not allow clicking on the `2nd` or `3rd` one if they not yet clicked on the first one.

[image]

I have access to the index of all those circles.

```
if(steps.indexOf(selector) != 0){
    alert("Please start by selecting your device.");
    return false;
}
```

Since my circle click bind using a one() so it only listening to an event one time only, after they click on a wrong order, my alert pop up, and when I click on the circle again, nothing will happen since the circle bind using one() function.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    let steps         = ['client', 'agent', 'ssid', 'tunnel', 'captivePortal', 'traffic'];
    let stepColors    = ['#4BB7E8', '#769BD0', '#9B83BC', '#82C341', '#53BD6D', '#30B795'];
    var selections    = [];
    var startIndex    = 0;
    var maxSelections = $('.circle-icon').length;

    $('div.col-sm-2').hide();
    $('div.col-sm-2').fadeIn(5000);

    $('div.options').hide();
    $('div.selected').hide();
    $('div.line').hide();

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
        $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState = { click: false, hover: false, focus: false }
    });


    function addGlow(selector, fadeColor) {
        selector.css("-webkit-box-shadow", "0 0 5px " + fadeColor, 1000);
        selector.css("-moz-box-shadow", "0 0 5px " + fadeColor, 1000);
        selector.css("box-shadow", "0 0 5px " + fadeColor, 1000);
    }

    function showOptions(selector, fadeColor) {

        var nextStep = '';

        /*======================================
        =            Circle Clicked            =
        ======================================*/

        $('.' + selector).on("click", function() {

            console.log(selector);
            console.log('startIndex = ',steps.indexOf(selector));

            //hide all the popovers

            if(steps.indexOf(selector) != 0){
                alert("Please start by selecting your device.");
                return false;
            }

            if (steps.indexOf(selector) != -1) {
                nextStep = steps[steps.indexOf(selector) + 1];
                // console.log(nextStep);
            }

            if(steps.indexOf(selector) == 1){
                $('.fa.fa-plus').hide();
            }else {
                $('.fa.fa-plus').show();
            }


            let circle = $(this);

            $('div.options').fadeOut('fast');

            circle.animate({backgroundColor: fadeColor }, 1400);
            circle.next().next('.options').slideDown(1000);

            $('.popover').remove();

            /*======================================
            =            Option Clicked            =
            ======================================*/

            circle.siblings('.options').find('span.option').one("click", function(event) {

                let selectedText = $(this).closest("p").prop("id");

                selections[selector] = selectedText;

                /*====================================
                =            Hide Options            =
                ====================================*/

                $(this).parent().parent().slideUp("slow", function() {

                    // $(this).parent().css("border", "orange 1px solid");
                    // return false;

                    // alert('HERE');

                    $(this).next('.selected').text(selectedText).fadeIn(1000);
                    $(this).next('.selected').css({"color": fadeColor }, 1000);
                    $(this).next('.selected').css("border", "3px solid " + fadeColor, 1000);

                    addGlow($(this).next('.selected'), fadeColor);

                    if (selector != 'traffic') {

                        startIndex++;

                        $(this).prev('.line').fadeIn('fast');
                        $(this).prev('.line').animate({"width": "300px"}, 1500);

                        addGlow($(this).prev('.line'), fadeColor);

                        circle.next().animate({backgroundColor: fadeColor }, 1400);
                    }

                    $('.popover').remove();

                    console.log(selections);
                    console.log(typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selections)))
                    console.log(Object.keys(selections).length);

                    if (Object.keys(selections).length == maxSelections) {

                        console.log(selections);

                        $('#sessionNameModal').modal('show');

                        $('#launch').on('click', function() {

                            var cleanId     = '#agentUuid-' + selections.agent.replace(".", "-");
                            var agentUuid   = $(cleanId).val();
                            var sessionName = $('#sessionName').val();

                            launch(selections, sessionName, agentUuid);
                        });
                    }

                });
            });

        });

    }

    function launch(selections, sessionName, agentUuid) {

        console.log('selections = ', selections);

        var data            = {};
        data.clientProfile  = selections.client;
        data.agent          = selections.agent;
        data.ssidProfile    = selections.ssid;
        data.tunnelProfile  = selections.tunnel;
        data.trafficProfile = selections.traffic;
        data.sessionName    = sessionName;
        data.agentUuid      = agentUuid;

        console.log("data", data);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/sessions/store',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value'),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            },
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('response = ', response);
                if (response.http_code >= 200 && response.http_code <= 207) {

                    toastr.options = {
                        "debug": false,
                        "newestOnTop": true,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "progressBar": false
                    };

                    console.log('%c -------->> Success <<--------', "color: green;");
                    toastr.success(sessionName + ' launched !');
                    window.location.replace("/sessions");

                } else {
                    toastr.options = {
                        "debug": false,
                        "newestOnTop": true,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "progressBar": false
                    };

                    toastr.error('can not launch.');

                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }

    for (i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
        showOptions(steps[i], stepColors[i]);
    }


    /*=================================
    =            i Clicked            =
    =================================*/

    $('.fa-info-circle').on("click", function(event) {

        // $(this).hide();


        // console.log($(this));
        // console.log($(this).parent());
        // console.log($(this).parent().parent());
        // console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent());
        // console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('span'));
        // console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('span').attr("circle-name"));
        //return false;

        $('.popover').remove();
        // $('.fa-info-circle').not(this).popover('hide');


        let object     = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('span').attr("circle-name");
        let objectName = $(this).closest("p").prop("id");


        var data        = {};
        data.object     = object;
        data.objectName = objectName;

        //console.log("data", data);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `/profiles/${object}/${objectName}`,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value'),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            },
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {

                console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));

                if (response.http_code >= 200 && response.http_code <= 207) {

                    //console.log('%c -------->> Success <<--------', "color: green;");

                    /*===============================
                    =            popover            =
                    ===============================*/

                    var dataContent = '';

                    console.log("object = ", object);
                    console.log("objectName = ", objectName);

                    // $('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr("title", response.name);
                    $('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr("data-original-title", response.name);

                    if(object == 'client'){
                        dataContent = `
                        <p><strong>flow_type</strong> : ${response.flow_type} </p>
                        <p><strong>subscriber_type</strong> : ${response.subscriber_type} </p>`;
                    }else if(object == 'agent'){
                        dataContent = `
                        <p><strong>uuid</strong> : ${response.agent_uuid} </p>
                        <p><strong>hostname</strong> : ${response.hostname} </p>`;
                    }else if(object == 'ssid'){
                        dataContent = `
                        <p><strong>uuid</strong> : ${response.name} </p>
                        <p><strong>ssid</strong> : ${response.ssid} </p>
                        <p><strong>vlan</strong> : ${response.vlan} </p>`;
                    }else if(object == 'tunnel'){
                        dataContent = `
                        <p><strong>uuid</strong> : ${response.name} </p>
                        <p><strong>encap_type</strong> : ${response.encap_type} </p>
                        <p><strong>tunnel_mac</strong> : ${response.tunnel_mac} </p>`;
                    }else if(object == 'captiveportal'){
                        dataContent = `
                        <p><strong>login_success_msg</strong> : ${response.login_success_msg} </p>
                        <p><strong>logout_url</strong> : ${response.logout_url} </p>
                        <p><strong>submit_button_value</strong> : ${response.submit_button_value} </p>`;
                    }else if(object == 'traffic'){
                        dataContent = `
                        <p><strong>name</strong> : ${response.name} </p>
                        <p><strong>enable_speedtest</strong> : ${response.enable_speedtest}</p>`;
                    }else{}


                    objectName = objectName.replace('.','-').split(' ').join('-');

                    console.log('objectName = ',objectName);

                    $('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr('data-content',dataContent);
                    $('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName+'[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');



                } else {

                    //console.log('%c -------->> Error <<--------', "color: red;");

                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#sessionName').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
    });


</script>
```

---

Is there a way to reset the one() on an object ?

I appologize, I don't even know how to word the question for that.

I hope someone out there know what I mean.

Comment: When the page loads add a class to the right 5 circles which sets `pointer-events: none`. When the first is clicked, remove the class from the second. Then the second is clicked, remove the class from the third. When the third is clicked...

Comment: Disable enable them in your desired sequence

Comment: please share html and css to replicate and debug issue

Answer (score 1):

Something like? It's not clear why you need to use the event only once.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div data-clickorder="0" data-wasclicked="false">click me</div>
    <div data-clickorder="1" data-wasclicked="false">click me</div>
    <div data-clickorder="2" data-wasclicked="false">click me</div>
    <div data-clickorder="3" data-wasclicked="false">click me</div>
    <div data-clickorder="4" data-wasclicked="false">click me</div>
    <script>
        var user_clicks = [];
        let tags = document.querySelectorAll('[data-clickorder]');
        tags.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
                if(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-wasclicked')==="true") return;
                let myClickOrder = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-clickorder');
                if(user_clicks.length === parseInt(myClickOrder)){
                    user_clicks.push(true);
                    event.currentTarget.setAttribute('data-wasclicked', 'true');
                    // do some stuff
                    console.log('Yay!');
                    event.currentTarget.innerText = "CLICKED!";
                }else{
                    // or dont
                    console.log("Nope!")
                    event.currentTarget.innerText = "NOT YET!";
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```